# Why is the output on my high voltage generator producing more amps than I would expect

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, step-up

I recently bought a high voltage generator of off amazon that apparantly steps up 3-6 volts to 400kV. I wanted to know how much amperage the output woud produce out off curiousity and measured it to be 15.82mA. So my question is: if im inputting 4.2V and 2.4A that gives me an input power of 10.08W wouldnt the output power have to be the same because the conservation of energy; that is if I step up the voltage by some amount then the amperage would have to step down by that amount too? So if the output is 400kV and 15.28mA that gives 6112 output power which seems way too high and not right so either

1. power is not conserved.
2. the manufactures are lying about the output voltage.
3. something else I am missing.

Comment: How did you measure it? Please note that 400kV at 15.82mA is 6300 watts so at least the voltage can not 400kV when you measure 15mA.

Comment: Even with a many megohm load the voltage is likely to collapse from 400kV to something much smaller. If you assemble a 400Mohm resistor from the highest value cheap resistors you can buy (10M * 40?) and place that in series with a 1 kilohm resistor, I wager you'll see much less than 1 Volt across that 1K resistor. (Stay safe!)

Comment: Is your output 400kV?  What type of meter are you using to measure current?  Ohm's Law is a law, which even you cannot break.

Comment: Was the input current measured as 2.4A through the current meter, with 4.2V at the input after the current measurement shunt; or is 2.4A the "rated" maximum available current on the label of your 4.2V input power supply? Remember a load only takes as much current as it needs.

Comment: One of the most-asked questions on this site is about power supply input current ratings, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: The input current and voltage was measured from my dc power supply then the output current with an ammeter. I didn’t even think about shorting it with the ammeter, thanks. I was just curious if this little $15 device from Amazon would actually create 400Kv and if it would supply dangerous amounts of current, or if it would just give a little burn or shock (without touching it of course).

Comment: > 400kV .. That's total bull. It's at most 1 kV. Don't fall for that marketing crap: they are lying.

Comment: 6112 µW @15,3mA output power is absolutely possible.

Answer (score 3):

No way is the open-circuit voltage of that thing **anything like** 400kV. Maybe 1/10 of that. Probably the easiest way to measure would be to get rounded smooth electrodes such as 1"/25mm ball bearings and test at what separation they *first* start to arc. Then look up the voltage. Graph from [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470495070.app3):

[image]

Note that pointy electrodes **greatly** reduce the voltage required to ionize the air. The A graph assumes diameter \$\ge\$ gap distance. A 40kV output would just jump maybe 12mm with large spherical electrodes and almost 50mm with needle electrodes.

I looked at a few videos to see if anyone has done this properly and didn't see any.  Folks either didn't attempt a measurement or did it badly (loading the output excessively with a probe). The spark method also loads the output at bit as you approach sparking because there will be a corona discharge (smell the ozone).

When you short the output with a multimeter on current range, it will have almost zero voltage, so virtually all the power dissipation is lost in the circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

Your current measurement probably loads the output excessively bringing the output voltage down considerably. I suspect you measured the short-circuit current, in which case the output voltage will be near zero during current measurement.

Comment: I did measure short circuit current. Should I attach a load then measure?

Comment: @BenjaminCollier, you short-circuited the output so the voltage would have been close to zero and *P = VI = 0 x 16 mA = 0* W. Never short a voltage source with an ammeter.

Comment: @Transistor in this case though, it might have been safer than the alternative

Comment: This is the voltage converter.  https://www.amazon.ca/gp/aw/d/B01GM9B4R0?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title

Answer (score 0):

> the manufactures are lying about the output voltage.

That's the one.

Such generators put out on the order of 300 V to 2 kV. No more than that. Don't believe marketing lies.

Comment: 400kV will arc more than 100mm in air.

Comment: Well, some of them arc 'bout 10mm or so, so I'd say it's a bit higher than 2kV, but still their claims are BS.